# user name is missing in top panel in ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, gnome-panel

username is missing in top panel in ubuntu 12.04 in Gnome Classic don't know why, i have tried to show it using dconf-tools but no success at all. How to show it back, i have tried to reset panels, but no success. Please help me.

Comment: Did you accidentally remove indicator-applet-complete from the panel? You could try: alt+right click the panel, add to panel, Indicator Applet Complete. Otherwise check that indicator-session is installed and that keys com.canonical.indicator.session user-show-menu and/or show-real-name-on-panel are set.

Answer (score 0):

Try Unity tweak tool or Ubuntu tweak, I realize these are primarily meant for Unity but I believe they work for the gnome fallback as well.

```
sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool
```

Ubuntu tweak can be found at [getdeb](http://www.getdeb.net/updates/ubuntu/13.04/), they should have a few versions available for various Ubuntu releases

Comment: sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool
[sudo] password for salman: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package unity-tweak-tool

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using? Try Ubuntu Tweak there are versions for each Ubuntu release.

Comment: i am using ubuntu 12.04, i have already used ubuntu tweak, but username is showing, i have also tried to reset gnome panels many times but no success at all :'(

Comment: I had disabled guest account and there was only one (mine) user left, that's why username and its menu was not showing, when i enabled  guest account then username displayed...